# Wifi hard blocked intel centrino wireless-N 2230 in ubunto 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: wireless

On my lenovo E130 laptop (intel centrino wireless-N 2230) i installed ubuntu 20.04 . For years before i used a dual boot system, in which i mostly used windows. Then i deleted the partitions and installed linux mint. Wifi didn't work and in the process of fixing it i installed ubuntu, but the problem persists. The problem is that wifi cannot be switched on and running rf kill showed wifi hardware block as "yes".

Pressing the wifi-button does not have any effect. I also unplugged and replugged the wifi card and checked the bios- all without effect. Then a friend found me this script
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)
For which i pasted the output here
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zx8HpQKHp3/
I assume that it could be some key combination other that the supposed one and tried a few combinations but no success so far.
I really hope someone can help ☺
Thanks a lot,best,
Nadine

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)  *You do mention Ubunto 20, which maybe a typo, but Ubuntu Core 20 isn't a desktop release which are all year.month format; year being used only for specialist snap only releases*

Comment: Thanks guiverc for your answer. I have installed ubuntu 20.04. Sorry, i adjusted the text description, i can see how it was misleading. Running ubuntu 20.04 i thought this is the right place for my question, but please let me know if not. Thanks